# What does 'HTML is escaping' mean?

Tags: html, escaping

Why is HTML is escaping = HTML is showing as it is?

Example: If I try to put any HTML tag here, it will not show that tag (it will simply work).
What is it? Escaping or not escaping?

Comment: It's HTML encoding. You type `<`, it gets encoded to HTML `&lt;`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Escaping in HTML means, that you are replacing some special characters with others. In HTML it means usually you replace e.g. `<` or `>` or `"` or `&`. These characters have special meanings in HTML.

Imagine, you write

```
<b>Hello, World!</b>
```

And the text will appear as **Hello, World!**. But sometime you don't want to have this behaviour. So you replace the `<` and `>`.

```
&lt;b&gt;Hello, World!&lt;/b&gt;
```

This will result in `<b>Hello, World!</b>`.